# How to simplify loop to take data from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, database, vba, loops

i have two worksheets ("Trade Log" and "Statistics") within one workbook. 
One is the database and the other the output to analyze the figures from the database. Now i want to code a loop that pulls the necessary information from the database into the output worksheet. More or less it is about checking 1-2 conditions and then sum it up to fill the output fields in the analyze worksheet.

I would now go ahead and code one loop for every single output field. But I am pretty damn sure that I can simplify this?

Thank you for your ideas!

This is my first loop for a single output... I  have around 120-140 outputs:

```
Sub update_statistics()

Dim lRow As Integer 'Last Row
Dim i As Integer 'Loop
Dim pair As String 'Currency Pair

lRow = Worksheets("Trade Log").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

'Total Stats Calculations

'Total Number of Trades

If Cells(3, 4).Value = "All" Then

Worksheets("Trade Log").Select

For i = 9 To lRow

    Worksheets("Statistics").Cells(7, 4).Value = (i + 1) - 8

Next i

Else

pair = Cells(3, 4).Value

Worksheets("Trade Log").Select

For i = 9 To lRow

    Worksheets("Statistics").Cells(7, 4).Value = 
 WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("D:D"), pair)

 Next i

 End If

 End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there really a need to do this in VBA?  Why can't you use standard functions?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something fundamental to your project because it looks like VBA would add complexity without serving a purpose.  I'd probably create an intermediate table Power Query and use worksheet functions to feed the analysis, but even PQ might be overkill.